# MSBuild errorMSB4126

Tags: msbuild, cruisecontrol.net, msbuild-task

I'm working on building scripts for Cruise control and within my ccnet.config file I have the following msbuild task defined:

```
<msbuild>
        <executable>C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe</executable>
        <workingDirectory>D:\ccnet\WorkingDirectories\Image Finder\Released\</workingDirectory>
        <projectFile>ImageFinder.sln</projectFile>
        <buildArgs>/p:DoEvents=false /p:Configuration="Release" /p:Platform="Any CPU" /verbosity:detailed</buildArgs>
        <targets>Rebuild</targets>
        <timeout>900</timeout>
</msbuild>
```

When I force a build i receive this error:

> errorMSB4126: The specified solution configuration "Release|Any CPU"
>   is invalid. Please specify a valid solution configuration using the
>   Configuration and Platform properties (e.g. MSBuild.exe Solution.sln
>   /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform="Any CPU") or leave those
>   properties blank to use the default solution configuration.

I was under the impression that with the msbuild script defined, everything would be working correctly. I have similar blocks defined elsewhere for other projects and they build fine. Does anyone have any insight as to why I would be receiving the above error?

**Update:**

This is the source control script for the active version we are working on and it builds fine.

```
 <msbuild>
        <executable>C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe</executable>
        <workingDirectory>D:\ccnet\WorkingDirectories\Image Finder\Active\</workingDirectory>
        <projectFile>ImageFinder.sln</projectFile>
        <buildArgs>/p:DoEvents=false /p:Configuration="Debug" /p:Platform="Any Cpu" /verbosity:detailed</buildArgs>
        <targets>Rebuild</targets>
        <timeout>900</timeout>
      </msbuild>
```

The only change that I could see was that the release build is using the "Release" config and not the "debug"
When I change it to the debug config it works, problem is that I cannot use the debug version. Any ideas why this small change would prevent the build from working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have a "Release|Any CPU" Configuration set up in your solution?  If yes, are any of the projects selected to build for that configuration?

If you eliminate the Platform argument, you'll get the default Platform for the Release configuration. Maybe that will get you going.

Comment: Thanks DaveE, You are completely spot on. The issue was that there was a Release32 config for the solution but not a Release.